# How do I find out the value to set the java_runtime_dir variable?

Tags: java, ubuntu

One of my Java projects requires setting up a variable `java_runtime_dir`. On Ubuntu, how do I find this directory? Is it the path to the java executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk`.